# React - Show Alert each time I click on an image

Tags: reactjs

Each time I click on an image, the **changeAlertVisibility** get called.

It then changes the **alertVisible** property of the state to true.

Then inside of the render method, if **alertVisible** value is true, an Alert (dialog box) should get rendered, otherwise nothing.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Alert from "./Alert";

class ListItem extends Component {
  state = {
    alertVisible: false
  };

  changeAlertVisibility = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      alertVisible: !prevState.alertVisible
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="card__body">
          <img
            src={this.props.photo.urls.small}
            onClick={() => this.changeAlertVisibility()}
          />

        {this.state.alertVisible ? (
          <Alert
            photoDesc={this.props.photo.description}
            photoPath={this.props.photo.urls.small}
            photoAlt={this.props.photo.id}
          />
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ListItem;
```

It works, but only by every second click.

The first time, I click an image, the value of **alertVisible** changes to true and the Alert pops up.

But the second time, the value of **alertVisible** changes to false and no Alert pops up.

The third time it works again and so on.

How can I change the code that the Alert pops up on each click?

Comment: Can't you pass the same click handler to `Alert` component and use there, maybe with a close button or something else? So when you do that your `alertVisible` state will be `false` again.

Comment: The behaviour you describe makes perfect sense because what you have implemented here is effectively a toggle state - click show the alert, click again hide, click show... and so on. This is fixable but the UX doesn't seem right to me unless you somehow _hide_ the alert after a period of time or using some other mechanism first? Otherwise it doesn't make sense to toggle the alert state at all because nothing has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this code is toggling alertVisible to the inverse of its previous state:

```
  changeAlertVisibility = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      alertVisible: !prevState.alertVisible
    }));
  };
```

So, initially `this.state.alertVisible` is `false`. After the first click, it will be set to `!this.state.alertVisible // => true`. On the second click, you are setting it back to `!this.state.alertVisible // => false`.

In order to achieve what you want, you need to ALWAYS set `alertVisible` to `true` like this:

```
  changeAlertVisibility = () => {
    this.setState({ alertVisible: true });
  };
```

Now, you probably want to set it back to false when the user closes the alert. I can't tell you exactly how to achieve that since I can't see the definition of your `Alert` component. However, I would add a `onClose` callback to your `Alert` that gets called when the alert is closed and then set `alertVisible` to false there:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Alert from "./Alert";

class ListItem extends Component {
  state = {
    alertVisible: false
  };

  changeAlertVisibility = (visible) => {
    this.setState({ alertVisible: visible });
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="card__body">
          <img
            src={this.props.photo.urls.small}
            onClick={() => this.changeAlertVisibility(true)}
          />

        {this.state.alertVisible ? (
          <Alert
            photoDesc={this.props.photo.description}
            photoPath={this.props.photo.urls.small}
            photoAlt={this.props.photo.id}
            onClose={() => this.changeAlertVisibility(false)}
          />
        ) : (
          null
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ListItem;
```